# c# application does not run on Win Server 2016

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, publish, windows-server-2016

i have been developing an c# application using VS2019 which was running on a Win 8.1 x64.
now i want to transfer the application to a VPS which was running Win Server 2016.
i tried copying all files from Releas folder to server bot when i ran the application nothing happened, not even a single error message.

so, i tried to publish app using VS and transfer setup files. then i installed the application on server and again nothing happened.

i read someone had told "Copy Local" property of references might help bot it did not go anywhere either.

the application has some dependencies and NuGet packages installed such as Microsoft SMO and MS.interop.excel

i found a log file on "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive" named "AppCrash_******" which includes some info but i did not find out what was the problem.

where i can find a log file for this occasion?
what might be the issue?

Edit 1:
the application is windows form application with .net 4.6.1

thank you for your help in advance

Comment: This needs some more info. What kind of "App" did you choose ? .NET framework 4.x and Winforms ? Console app ? .NET 5 ? Core ? are you *sure* there are no dependencies, drive letters, paths set incorrectly.. also check if your VPN is able to download Framework 4.x or other .NET updates. I've seen .net Framework 4.7 or 4.8 Winforms not working on Server 16, while 4.5 ran fine.

Comment: @Goodies the application is a windows form app and i am using .net framework 4.6.1,
i am not sure that i have done something wrong with dependencies, but wherever in the code that i was referring to a path or any local variable (like server name for SQL) i put them in a Try&Catch so that i can run through and show the error message. 
in terms of dependencies i have used them as always, i added a dll as reference and used it in code.

Comment: Ok thanks I changed the tags on your question. About the error messages: have you tried running the app from a command prompt Console ? when it yields a Console.Write or Debug.Write error message you will see it in the console. Put some Debug.WriteLine() messages at the start of your program.cs. Also, try compile your program in Debug mode, not release. If possible, run a  test in 32-bit mode (x86)

Comment: @Goodies Thanks man, i am going to try it and then i will report

Comment: There's no usable information in the question. There's nothing wrong with Windows Server. The application itself must handle exceptions and log errors. Even if an application doesn't handle errors, unhandled exceptions will be written to the Application event log. If the application hides exceptions with `catch{}` though, there may not be any way to find out what's wrong

Comment: Is the correct NET Runtime installed? Although even that failure would be logged in the Event log

Comment: Yes agree, the Application event log must also be checked. It can be found with Start and type *Event Viewer* in W10, I suppose it is the same in Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

so, it was a VS C++ package issue.
i installed all VS C++ packages and problem solved.
obviously one of the dependencies needed that